# Why the word "ride" is used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

"Ride a bike", for every vehicle the word 'drive' is used.For example drive car, drive a bus etc.But for a particular vehicle 'bike' why is the word drive not used,and instead of drive the word ride is used in sentences.

Comment: When you in a car, but not the driver, you are riding.

Comment: It's somewhat idiomatic. There is no *logical* explanation why we don't say *drive a bike*. (At least not that I'm aware of.)

Comment: See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72399/191178) on ELU for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

"Drive" seems to be idiomatic for most *motorized* vehicles, while *ride* is idiomatic for *unpowered* or *self-powered* vehicles.  As you say, you "drive" a *car, bus, train, boat, motorcycle, scooter, truck, tractor, carriage, taxi, limousine, or hearse* ... but you "ride" a *bicycle, tricycle, unicycle, skateboard,  toboggan, or surfboard.*

You also ride a *horse, camel, elephant, donkey, pony, mule, yak, ox, reindeer, ostrich*, or any other animal that can be ridden.

There is at least one exception:  Because a [hoverboard](https://i02.hsncdn.com/is/image/HomeShoppingNetwork/prodfull/air-ride-pro-self-balancing-hoverboard-wbackpack-bag-d-201610311758025~511266_001.jpg) is so much like a skateboard, most people seem to prefer "ride" for this, even though it has an electric motor.  In the same way [small electric scooters](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Qtg4L%2BJmL._SX425_.jpg) are "ridden" -- unless you [sit down on them](https://c.ndtvimg.com/ather-340-electric-scooter_625x300_1528116633878.jpg), in which case either "ride" or "drive" might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a technical reason why this is incorrect (you would be understood), but anything that is not powered by a motor (bicycle, scooter, horse, etc.) is ridden.

Comment: The other day, I was *riding* a motorbike.